# How to check whether the list of string has same name?

Tags: python, string, text, label

I want to categorize multiple strings into some of labels. For example, if the string has a word "Cat", then I will give it label number 1. Another example, if I have string of "Dog", then I will give it label 2, and so on.

I have tried comparing the strings but it gave error.

I used import os but still have no idea to add label on it.

```py
import os
path = "check"
dirList = os.listdir(path)


with open("check.txt", "w") as a:
    for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(path):
        for filename in files:
            #print(i)
            mylist = filename.split("_")

            #for mlist in mylist:
```

The expected result:

```
Cat_0 0
Cat_1 0
Cat_2 0
Cat_3 0
Dog_0 0
Dog_1 0
Dog_2 0
Dog_3 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I would solve this by creating a dictionary of label names corresponding to their label values.

```
labels = {
    'Cat': 0,
    'Dog': 1,
    //etc
}
```

Then, when you go through each file in your directory, for each file, consider if the filename contains the label name.  If so, give it the label value.  You could also extract this logic into its own function so it would be clearer.

```
def find_label(labels, to_label): #'labels' is your dictionary of labels, to_label is the string you want to label.
    for key in labels.keys():
        if key in to_label:
            return labels[key]
    return -1 #If you've made it here, none of your labels apply
```

Once you have that function, you simply call it and use the results each time you have a new file that you want to label.

```
for filename in files:
    label = find_labels(label, filename)
    #Write your label to a file or whatever you want to do with it.
```

If you have too many labels that writing the dictionary out literally is a problem, then create the dictionary with python.

```
label_names = [] #A list of all your label names that you've read into a list
labels = {}
count = 0
for name in label_names:
    labels[name] = count
    count+=1
```

Now, your labels dictionary contains all your labels with unique label values that count up from 0.

Comment: Thank you, but the problem is there are hundreds of labels, so it will be cumbersome if i create dictionary then give number one by one to the dictionary

Comment: Then you just need to create the dictionary programmatically instead of typing it out.  Read all of your labels into a list, then go over that list putting them into the dictionary, and increment a count after you add them to the dictionary.

Comment: I tried it but some of the number gave error. It starts good at numbering, but somehow it cannot put new label value

Comment: Share the error and snippets of the code you used to produce it.  There is no reason this shouldn't work.